# br tag not rendering block level in IE unless two br tags are specified

Tags: html, css

I've got a browser issue with br tag in internet explorer. I realize in chrome and firefox

specifying a br tag after a span tag enforces a new line however in to get the same effect in internet explorer I have to use two br tags.

Could any one point me to why this is the case.

eg in Chrome:

```
<span style='float:left;min-width:120px;width:120px'>text</span><br /> enforces a new line
```

but in IE:

```
<span style='float:left;min-width:120px;width:120px'>text</span><br /><br /> rather enforces a new line
```

NB the span tags have a min-width and width attribute specified and is floated left

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the span is floating left, it's slightly murky, what the `<br />` should do. You should specify `clear: left` in its style:

```
<span style="float:left;min-width:120px;width:120px">text<span><br style="clear:left"> enforces a new line
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you only want 'text' to be enclosed in your span tag, but it looks like your closing 'span' tag isn't a closing tag after all. You may be getting this unexpected output because IE is interpreting this as the start of a new  tag.

Comment: I have the span tag closed properly in code. I've corrected my post